# Deck frame is 1/2" out of square, worth fixing it?

Tags: framing, deck

When I was building my deck frame, I naively assumed both 2x8x8 had the same length. It turned out that one of them was 1/2" longer. Now the frame has the measurements as shown. Is it worth moving corner D a little bit to the right to make the frame square? To do so, I'll remove four nails and then hammer them back to the position 1/2" to the right. I'm worried that the new nail position is too close to the previous position.

[image]

Comment: Whether you "should" do something is usually a matter of opinion and off topic here. If you're asking about the viability of re-nailing boards, please revise to make your post specifically about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely correct this out of square issue if the deck floor has yet to be installed. Easy now. It will also make for uniform planking across the deck. Also any miter joints that may come into place with railings will also fit better without a lot of extra fuss.

The nail repositioning should be no problem. Just fully extract the old nails and discard. Then install the appropriate number of new nails at slightly offset locations.

Answer (score 1):

If the rim joists (or at least corners `C` and `D`) aren't yet attached to anything, just give corner `D` a few light blows with your hammer toward corner `C` until your diagonals are equal, then fix the joists in place.

Once your diagonals are equal, the rectangle will be "square" (yes, I see the oxymoron there...).